# Why does my ImageButton keep the gray from a blank image on its sides?

Tags: android, imagebutton, titlebar

I'm creating a custom titleBar and I'm putting some imageButtons in there, and when you set the ImageButton as default it's just gray. When you assign it a value it should completely change its view to that image.

Mine for some odd reason is setting the image correctly, but keeping the gray borders that the default ImageButton has. Is there a reason why this is?

Here's a picture of whats happening: 
[image]

Here's my xml file for the titleBar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_flash_card_display"
        android:textColor="@color/bluenessText" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">   


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/flashCard_show_amount_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="right" />

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grey box you see is actually the background. So, when you set the `ImageButton` drawable, it sets the image, not the background. You can either use `imageButton.setBackgroundDrawable(null);` (or `imageButton.setBackground(null)` on API 16+), or instead set the background to whatever drawable you are currently using for the foreground.

Comment: Unfortunately When I try to change the color of the background it doesn't change... I've tried changing it with the setBackGroundColor
And the setBackGroundDrawable is depreciated and I'm only using api 8 so I can't use setBackground since its api 16. >.<
Edit: I think I figured it out. The image itself has some white around the edges thats what I'm seeing probably. Lol...THanks!

Comment: Keep in mind, `setBackgroundDrawable` is only deprecated on version 16+. Use it for anything less than 16. ;) But I'm glad you got it worked out!